# jQuery Galleria 'fatal error: no theme found.' in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, galleria

[Galleria v 1.2](https://github.com/aino/galleria) works fine in FF, SF and Chrome, but it raises this message in all IEs "fatal error: no theme found." Anybody seen it before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have, and a solution that works is to place a link to that theme in the page, i.e.:

```
<script src="path/to/your/theme.js"></script>
```

But it will sometimes still throw this error for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note. A lot of the times you get the error message without there being any errors. I find that hiding the error with some CSS to be helpful:

```
 <style>
  .galleria-errors
  {
      visibility:hidden;
      display:none;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is just set debug to false;

http://galleria.io/docs/options/debug/

Answer (score 0):

Change the Galleria debug setting true to false.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Galleria.loadTheme("http://www.luberonexperience.com/galleria/themes/folio/galleria.folio.min.js");
    jQuery.noConflict(); jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#flickr_bonnieux_976").data("options",{"autoplay":5000,"transition":"fade","transitionSpeed":0,"showInfo":true,"imageCrop":true,"carousel":true,"debug":false});
        slickr_flickr_start();
    });
</script>
```